# npm install -g n appeared to work but n command not recognized

Tags: macos, npm

I am setting up a new Mac and trying to install n so that I can manage node versions for my development project. It works great on my old mac but I can't seem to get things sorted on the new Macbook Pro M1.

First, I installed it with `npm install -g n` and it reported that it installed the package:

```
npm i n
added 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 1s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

But when I use `n 10.14.1` to attempt to install a specific version of node, I get this error:

```
n 10.14.1
zsh: command not found: n
```

Update: Here is what I get from $PATH in terminal (I switched from zsh to bash so that I could try to match my old Mac's setup):

```
-bash: /opt/openssl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin: No such file or directory
```

My .bash_profile contents is:

> export PATH="${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"

Update: My npm and corepack folders are located at `/usr/local/bin/npm`

Everything else I've installed (@angular/cli and n) is being placed in `/users/[me]/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/`

Comment: Because your global npm folder is not in your $PATH. Maybe if you use `npx n 10.14.1` it will work

Comment: @MickaelB. thanks but can you tell me how to fix it so that I can use n? I'm just setting up a new mac for Angular development and need to try to set it up like my old mac that works as expected.

Comment: Can you run `whereis npm` or `npm -g` to see where is your global npm is located

Comment: @MickaelB. thanks, I've updated my question with this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your `.npm-global`'s `bin` folder in your `$PATH`

In your `.bashrc` or `.profile`, add:

```bash
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

---

See [point 4 of this doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally#manually-change-npms-default-directory)